# Show that for each $k \in \mathbb N$ with $k \geq 4$ there exists a prime number $p$ such that $\Omega (N_p) = k.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> For $N \in \mathbb N,$ let $\Omega (N)$ denote the number of prime factors of $N$ counting multiplicities. For a prime number $p,$ let $N_p = p (p + 2) (p + 4).$ Show that for any $k \in \mathbb N$ with $k \geq 4$ there exists a prime number $p$ such that $\Omega (N_p) = k.$

What I can see is that $N_p$ has at least four prime factors (counting multiplicities) for $p \gt 3.$ But I don't see how it helps in solving the problem. Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It might help to observe that $\Omega(N_p) = \Omega(p) + \Omega(p+2) + \Omega(p+4) = 1 + \Omega(p+2) + \Omega(p+4)$.  So it's enough to show that as $p$ ranges over all primes, $\Omega(p+2) + \Omega(p+4)$ takes on values $3, 4, \ldots$.  I'm not sure this helps though.

Comment: There are an infinite number of non-twin primes. Therefore $\Omega(p+2)$ and $\Omega(p+4)$ are essentially unbounded for a random large prime. That's really informal and doesn't show that *all* $k \ge4$ are outputs of $\Omega(N_p)$, but maybe it'll be a useful line of thought.

Comment: Is this really a contest math question?

Comment: @acreativename: It is a sample question of a contest math (PhD Screening Test) problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have a (possible) solution. It stands on somewhat shaky ground, I'll admit.

We know from Legendre that any arithmetic sequence $ak+d$ where $(a,d)=1$ contains an infinite number of primes. Consider the sequences $15ak$, $15ak-2$ and $15ak-4$, with $2 \nmid ak$. The first sequence contains no primes; the other two contain infinitely many primes.

Now, choose an odd $a$ such that $\Omega(15a) = z \ge 2$; we can do this for an arbitrarily large $z$ by adding more factors to $a$. We can restrict $k$ to the odd primes so that $\Omega(15ak) = z+1$.

(Note that we can also use $a=k=1$ to get $(11,13,15)$ for which $\Omega(N_p)=4$. Similarly, $a=3, k=1 \implies \Omega(N_p) = 5$.)

For any odd $a$, the set $R = \{15ak-4 \mid k \in \mathbb{P}, k \ne 2\}$ contains infinitely many primes. Then via Chen's theorem, there are infinitely many* $r \in R$ where $\Omega(r)=1$ or $\Omega(r)=2$.

Then there must exist* some $k \in \mathbb{P}$ such that $p = 15k-4 \in \mathbb{P}$ and $\Omega(p+2) \in \{1,2\}$. $\Omega(p+2) = 2$ will almost certainly be easier to find. The remaining factors come from $15ak$, with $\Omega(N_p) = 3 + \Omega(15ak)$.

---

*I feel these two implications may be shaky. I'm firmer about Chen's theorem, as I'm all but certain it works for arithmetic sequences. The last implication I'm less certain of. If we allow composite $k$ it would certainly be true. But then $\Omega(p+4)$ becomes unstable and unpredictable.

If both of these are untrue, this *does* still solve the case of $\Omega(p(p+2))$ or $\Omega(p(p+4))$, but not all three factors.

Comment: Dirichlet proved the conjecture stated by Legendre and Gauss, not Legendre itself.